# Getting raw passwords from a salt

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

I have changed my website over to Laravel and using their method of storing passwords.

However all my olds users passwords were stored differently using salts. My inital aim was to simply run all the users and their salt through some code to get the raw password and then run them through the Laravel process.

However, I cannot figure out how to get the raw passwords. The code to generate the salt and passwords was given to me and it was cut and paste job before I knew too much.

So, old way of creating a users password:

```
// Create a salt for password
$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

// Hash for password
$password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

// Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times...
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
{ 
  $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
}
```

And then when logging in:

```
$check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
{ 
  $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
}
```

Is it possible with what I have to reverse the changes and get the raw passwords?

If needs for testing, a hashed password and salt:

```
password: f7e98af40e141e8abdae42c6e4c3375ff7eede881678a07b18898724240035de
salt: 3eb9507334ff0ab2
```

Thanks.

Comment: No. Hashes are one way.

Comment: Thought so, Plab B it is then.

Comment: I'm afraid not if salt is random.

Comment: @JohnConde So are most streets in NYC and MTL ;-) *Downtown*

Comment: @Fred-ii- So very true!

Comment: A suggestion. You could add a field to your user table called old_password and mark all existing users as true.  Then in your authentication if it is an old password check it the old way and if it is a new user then the Laravel method would be used.  I have done this successfully in migrations of frameworks in the past.  Good luck!

Comment: After thinking about it I am going to kill two birds with 1 email. Im going to send all users a 'We're Back' type of email with a link to reset the password which is easy enough with Laravel. If the users care enough then entering the same password twice wont be too much harm. Slight annoyance but...

Comment: Yes, that idea sounds good. You could also add an extra column as a set flag, if the user updated to a new hashing method. You could send out periodic emails afterwards reminding them to change their password, while using a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Since hashing is a one-way function, you can't go through the database and convert the old hashes to new Laravel (bcrypt) hashes.

You will probably have to implement authentication twice, and work toward moving users when they login to the new system. I would suggest adding a database field to represent whether a password has been converted to the new system or not, and based on that, use two login mechanisms.

Based on the email or username, look up the user in the database and see if they are using the old or new auth system. If it's the old system, check the password using your existing auth and if it all checks out, log the user in using `Auth::loginUsingId($userId)`. We also have the opportunity to upgrade the user to the new auth system since the plaintext password is still available in the request. Run it through `Hash::make($plaintext)` and store it, and note down in the auth version field that the user has been transitioned.

If the user is using the new auth, use `Hash::check($plaintext, $hashedPassword)` to check the password and as before, login with `Auth::loginUsingId($userId)`.

You could also look at [extending](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending) Laravel so that you could use `Auth::attempt()` and have it determine which hashing algorithm to use under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is migrate the data into the new system then make the new system front-facing then send all users a password reset request from admin account (using some script). So that they can reset their passwords using the new system's algorithm in the new database.

Its like re-registering passwords into the new database.

It doesn't matter what kind of salt it is, you can always ask the user to re-enter their password.